# Use non-virtual folder in Docker compose as volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm configuring a Docker compose file in order to start and integrate several services.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    ...
    volumes:
     - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    ...
  solr:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./data/solr/:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    ...
```

When doing this, all nessessary folders are created within the folder I run **docker-compose up**.

Problem 1: This folders have no generic rights and docker is not able to store/write all information and the containers throw errors. Which rights do those folders need (Windows, Linux)?

As a second approach I used the volumes definition to create the data storage.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    ...
    volumes:
     - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    ...
  solr:
    ...
    volumes:
      - solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    ...
volumes:
     mariadb:
     solr:
```

In this setting the data folders for the volumes are created within a virtual machine and the containers can write/read all data without a problem. But the folders are somehow hidden in the Hyper-V Environment in Windows.

Problem 2: How can i define the *named* volumes in this section in a way that they point to a defined folder outside a VM on my physical drives (Windows, Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1: This folders have no generic rights and docker is not able to store/write all information and the containers throw errors. Which rights do those folders need (Windows, Linux)?

The directory on the host needs the permission bits set so that the user inside the container can write to it. The mapping of usernames and group names inside the container and on the host may be different due to different /etc/passwd and /etc/group files. Therefore you need to set the permissions based on the uid and gid of the user inside the container when configuring permissions on the host.

> Problem 2: How can i define the named volumes in this section in a way that they point to a defined folder outside a VM on my physical drives (Windows, Linux)?

There's no workaround for setting the permissions on the directory on the host if you don't use named volumes. The only reason named volumes don't have this issue is because they get initialized to the permissions and ownership (along with the directory contents) of the image when they are empty or created and attached to a container. Host volumes (aka bind mounts) do not have this initialization feature.

If you need to refer to a volume by name instead of by path for a specific use case, then there is a plugin called [local persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) that may solve your issue. I've yet to encounter a scenario where this was needed so I have no feedback on how well it works.